# How Do I Get MCPE 0.8.1 Realms?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

How do I get minecraft 0.8.1 PE realms?
I went in the options and logged into realms and it doesn't show realms!
How do I get realms?

Answer (score -4):

You have to pay for it on the website..

Comment: Care to add in anything to explain why this solves the problem?